# Assign Javascript Function Output to PHP session variable with native ajax [without JQuery & without user action (no click)]

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, parameter-passing

my js knowledge is near to zero.

i want to

1. get screen width in my *index.php* with js (*no problem*)
2. assign js output value to a php session variable with ajax (**?!?**)
3. add those values to database for future aims (*no problem*)

Also,

- I don't want to use jquery library. (My only js usage will be at this
  point)
- I don't want any button to click. (no visitor action)

what I tried is below. I created 2 pages: *`index.php`* and *`dealviewportwidth.php`*

*index.php* will return viewport width, will done ajax part also and I will assign the value in *dealviewportwidth.php* by `$_GET`.

I fail, the session variable is not set. What to correct in **// assignWidthToPHP** part in *index.php* so the session variable will be set?

**index.php ( return width by js, deal with ajax )**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getViewportWidth()
{
    var viewportwidth;

    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
    {
      viewportwidth = window.innerWidth
    }

    // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
     && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
     'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
    {
       viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
    }

    // older versions of IE
    else
    {
       viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth
    }
    return(viewportwidth);
}

// assignWidthToPHP
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var width = getViewportWidth();
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/dealviewportwidth.php?w="+width,false);
xhttp.send();

</script>
```

**dealviewportwidth.php**

```
<?php

session_start ();

$_SESSION["w"] = $_GET["w"];

var_dump($_SESSION["w"]);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is working on my computer, I just changed this line :

```
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/dealviewportwidth.php?w="+width,false);
```

To

```
xhttp.open("GET", "/dealviewportwidth.php?w="+width,false);
```

Write a third script :

**check.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
echo $_SESSION["w"];
```

First open index.php, it will call dealviewportwidth.php in background
Then open check.php it should display your data.

If you want to call dealviewportwidth.php directly from your browser, test if w parameter is set :

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_GET["w"]))
{
    $_SESSION["w"] = $_GET["w"];
}   
var_dump($_SESSION["w"]);

?>
```

Comment: You 1st run index.php, and then the other one and worked?  Why i couldnt then? May it be browser dependant?

Comment: dealviewportwidth.php is called in background by index.php, you can see the call in the network inspector of your browser. What browser do you use ?

Comment: I edited my answer, I think it should be easier for you to display your session var in a third script.

Comment: ok,i got it. I also checked from ie's network inspector and it's there. SO WHY I CAN NOT SET SESSION VAR BY CLICKING `dealviewportwidth.php`

Comment: by calling directly dealviewportwidth you don't pass the "w" parameter, so $_GET["w"] is NULL, and you clear your session var... Try to visit directly "dealviewportwidth.php?w=foo", it should do the job

Comment: check.php also works and I see the result however, it's the 3rd page. And including it into `dealviewportwidth.php` did not work. Inserting into mysql should be done without clicking any link or button so do you have any suggestion to call 3rd page? it's weird situation. I feel that it should be done with 2 pages.

Comment: if I would know "foo" then I wouldn't need ajax

Comment: You don't understand how ajax work... You call index.php in your browser, it call dealviewportwidth.php in background and store your width in session. Then all your script can get it. But if you call dealviewportwidth.php without any parameter, this line $_SESSION["w"] = $_GET["w"]; erase the session. that's all. If you want to recall dealviewportwidth.php directly, add a test before (I edit my answer again)

Comment: You don't have to use a session... Just use dealviewportwidth.php directly to store your data in your database. Your script is working, you have your parameter, so store it

Comment: endless thanks for your lots of explanations in comments